# How to mark up different entry types (index/glossary/acronym/notation) at the same time in datagidx package?

Tags: indexing, glossaries, acronyms, datatool

I came across `datagidx` package, which is part of the `datatool` bundle, the killing feature of this package is that you can use it independently, not relying on external indexing applications, e.g., `xindy` or `makeidx`. One more feature, is that you can use it to address index, glossary (definitions), acronyms (abbreviations), notations, and it can be further extended to include customized databases as well, all by one package. I tend to keep the databases separate in different tex files and use `\input{<filenamen>}` in the main file to call for these databases.
Sometimes, one would like to do different things with different keywords in the text, the following possibilities might be in need:

- some words to appear in glossary + index
- some words to appear in acronyms + index
- some words to appear in glossary + acronyms + index

**Question:**
How to address this need for these different possibilities using one command at a time? keeping in mind, and to make life easier, one would like to use always the short version of the entry in the text flow (to avoid typos as much as possible), while displaying the long version in the target list.

**Notes:**
Please Make sure to have at least  version 2.13 of `datatool` bundle which will load `datagidx`

Comment: The `xargs` and `xparse` packages allow for complex macro construction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The example below defines some commands that allow you to add entries to multiple databases. You can then use the example command `\xgls` instead of `\gls` and it will index the entries for each of the databases. So if `pdf` is in the `glossary`, `acronym` and `index` database, `\xgls{pdf}` will add a location to each database, whereas if `html` is only in the `acronym` and `index` database, `\xgls{html}` will only add locations to those two database.

**Edit:** `\newacronymentry` has an extra argument to indicate the description to be used in the glossary.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datagidx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newgidx{glossary}{Glossary}
\newgidx{acronyms}{Acronyms}
\newgidx{index}{Index}

% Syntax: \newacronym[options]{short}{long}
% Defines an acronym that also has an entry in the index

\newcommand{\newacronym}[3][]{%
  \newterm[database={index},sort={#3},label={index.#2}]%
   {\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}%
  \newacro[database={acronyms},label={acronym.#2},#1]%
   {\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}{#3}%
}

% Syntax: \newentry[options]{label}{name}
% Defines a glossary entry that also appears in the index

\newcommand{\newentry}[3][]{%
  \newterm[database={glossary},label={glossary.#2},#1]{#3}%
  \newterm[database={index},label={index.#2},#1]{#3}%
}

% Syntax: \newacronymentry[options]{short}{long}{description}
% Like \newacronym but also adds the entry to the glossary

\newcommand{\newacronymentry}[4][]{%
  \newterm[database={glossary},label={glossary.#2},%
    sort={#2},#1,description={#4}]%
    {\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}%
  \newterm[database={index},sort={#3},label={index.#2}]%
    {\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}%
  \newacro[database={acronyms},label={acronym.#2},#1]%
    {\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}{#3}%
}

% Syntax: \xgls{label}
% If acronym.#1 exists use that and index
% Otherwise if glossary.#1 exists, use that and index the others.
% Otherwise if index.#1 use index.#1
% If none of the above, just do \gls{label}

\newcommand{\xgls}[1]{%
  \iftermexists{acronym.#1}%
  {%
    \acr{acronym.#1}%
    \iftermexists{glossary.#1}%
    {\glsadd{glossary.#1}}%
    {}%
    \iftermexists{index.#1}%
    {\glsadd{index.#1}}%
    {}%
  }%
  {%
    \iftermexists{glossary.#1}%
    {%
      \gls{glossary.#1}%
      \iftermexists{index.#1}%
      {\glsadd{index.#1}}%
      {}%
    }%
    {%
      \iftermexists{index.#1}%
      {\gls{index.#1}}%
      {%
        \gls{#1}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

% Define some acronyms

\newacronym{html}{hypertext markup language}
\newacronym{csv}{comma-separated variable}

% Define some glossary entries

\newentry[description={A typesetting language},sort={TeX}]{tex}{\TeX}
\newentry[description={A format of \TeX},sort={LaTeX}]{latex}{\LaTeX}

% Define some acronyms that also go in the glossary

\newacronymentry{pdf}{portable document format}{A file format}

% Define a term that isn't an acronym or a glossary entry

\newterm[database=index]{sample}

\begin{document}

First use: \xgls{html}.
First use: \xgls{csv}.
First use: \xgls{pdf}.
Reference \xgls{tex}.
Reference \xgls{latex}.
Reference the \xgls{sample} term.

\clearpage

Second use: \xgls{html}.
Second use: \xgls{csv}.
Second use: \xgls{pdf}.
Reference \xgls{tex}.
Reference \xgls{latex}.
Reference the \xgls{sample} term.

\printterms[database=acronyms,columns=1,location=hide]

\printterms[database=glossary,columns=1,location=hide]

\printterms[database=index,columns=1]

\end{document}
```

Page 1:

[image: Image of first page]

Page 2:

[image: Image of second page]

**Edit 2:**

If you're undecided as to whether you want to use `datagidx` or `glossaries`, you could try the following approach:

First we have two files, which I'm going to call `test-datagidx.tex` and `test-glossaries.tex`. They both define the same control sequences, but the first uses the `datagidx` package and the second uses the `glossaries` package. If you stick to using those commands in your document, it should be possible to switch between the two packages. **Edit:** However, I strongly recommend that you stick to using `glossaries` as it's much more efficient than `datagidx`. Although the two packages do similar things, they have a very different internal structure, which means they aren't compatible, so there are some things you can do in one but not the other so stick to just using the `test-glossaries.tex` code below, if possible.

Here's the first file `test-datagidx.tex`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{datagidx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newgidx{glossary}{Glossary}
\newgidx{acronyms}{Acronyms}
\newgidx{index}{Index}

% Syntax: \newacronymterm[options]{short}{long}
% Defines an acronym that also has an entry in the index

\newcommand{\newacronymterm}[3][]{%
  \newterm[database={index},sort={#3},label={index.#2},#1]%
   {\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}%
  \newacro[database={acronyms},label={acronym.#2},#1]%
   {\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}{#3}%
}

% Syntax: \newentry[options]{label}{name}
% Defines a glossary entry that also appears in the index

\newcommand{\newentry}[3][]{%
  \newterm[database={glossary},label={glossary.#2},#1]{#3}%
  \newterm[database={index},label={index.#2},#1]{#3}%
}

% Syntax: \newacronymentry[options]{short}{long}{description}
% Like \newacronym but also adds the entry to the glossary

\newcommand{\newacronymentry}[4][]{%
  \newterm[database={glossary},label={glossary.#2},%
    sort={#2},#1,description={#4}]%
    {\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}%
  \newterm[database={index},sort={#3},label={index.#2},#1]%
    {\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}%
  \newacro[database={acronyms},label={acronym.#2},#1]%
    {\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}{#3}%
}

% Just an index entry
\newcommand{\newindexentry}[2][]{%
   \newterm[database=index,label={index.#2},#1]{#2}%
}

% Syntax: \xgls[format]{label}
% If acronym.#1 exists use that and index
% Otherwise if glossary.#1 exists, use that and index the others.
% Otherwise if index.#1 use index.#1
% If none of the above, just do \gls{label}

\newcommand{\xgls}[2][]{%
  \ifstrempty{#1}{\def\fmtopt{}}{\def\fmtopt{[#1]}}%
  \iftermexists{acronym.#2}%
  {%
    \acr{acronym.#2}%
    \iftermexists{glossary.#2}%
    {\glsadd{glossary.#2}}%
    {}%
    \iftermexists{index.#2}%
    {\expandafter\glsadd\expandafter{\fmtopt index.#2}}%
    {}%
  }%
  {%
    \iftermexists{glossary.#2}%
    {%
      \gls{glossary.#2}%
      \iftermexists{index.#2}%
      {\glsadd{index.#2}}%
      {}%
    }%
    {%
      \iftermexists{index.#2}%
      {\expandafter\gls\expandafter{\fmtopt index.#2}}%
      {%
        \expandafter\gls\expandafter{\fmtopt #2}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}


\newcommand{\PrintAcronyms}{%
  \printterms[database=acronyms,columns=1,location=hide]%
}

\newcommand{\PrintGlossary}{%
   \printterms[database=glossary,columns=1,location=hide]%
}

\newcommand{\PrintIndex}{%
   \printterms[database=index,showgroups]%
}
```

Here's the second file (`test-glossaries.tex`):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,xindy]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\newglossary[ilg]{index}{ind}{idx}{\indexname}%

\makeglossaries

\SetCustomStyle
\renewcommand{\acrfullformat}[2]{#1 (\MakeTextUppercase{#2})}

% Syntax: \newacronym[options]{short}{long}
% Defines an acronym that also has an entry in the index

\newcommand{\newacronymterm}[3][]{%
  \newacronym[name={\MakeTextUppercase{#2}},#1]{acronym.#2}{#2}{#3}%
  \newglossaryentry{index.#2}{name={\MakeTextUppercase{#2}},%
  type={index},sort={#2},#1,description={\nopostdesc}}%
}

% Syntax: \newentry[options]{label}{name}
% Defines a glossary entry that also appears in the index

\newcommand{\newentry}[3][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{glossary.#2}{name={#3},#1}%
  \newglossaryentry{index.#2}{name={#3},type={index},%
  #1,description={\nopostdesc}}%
}

% Syntax: \newacronymentry[options]{short}{long}{description}
% Like \newacronym but also adds the entry to the glossary

\newcommand{\newacronymentry}[4][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{glossary.#2}{name={\MakeTextUppercase{#2}},%
    sort={#2},description={#4},#1}%
  \newglossaryentry{index.#2}{name={\MakeTextUppercase{#2}},type={index},%
  #1,description={\nopostdesc}}%
  \newacronym[name={\MakeTextUppercase{#2}},#1]{acronym.#2}{#2}{#3}%
}

% Just an index entry
\newcommand{\newindexentry}[2][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{index.#2}{name={#2},%
  type={index},sort={#2},#1,description={\nopostdesc}}%
}

% Syntax: \xgls[format]{label}
% If acronym.#1 exists use that and index
% Otherwise if glossary.#1 exists, use that and index the others.
% Otherwise if index.#1 use index.#1
% If none of the above, just do \gls{label}

\newcommand{\xgls}[2][]{%
  \ifglsentryexists{acronym.#2}%
  {%
    \ifglsentryexists{glossary.#2}%
    {\glsadd{glossary.#2}}%
    {}%
    \ifglsentryexists{index.#2}%
    {\glsadd[#1]{index.#2}}%
    {}%
    \gls[#1]{acronym.#2}%
  }%
  {%
    \ifglsentryexists{glossary.#2}%
    {%
      \ifglsentryexists{index.#2}%
      {\glsadd{index.#2}}%
      {}%
      \gls{glossary.#2}%
    }%
    {%
      \ifglsentryexists{index.#2}%
      {\gls[#1]{index.#2}}%
      {%
        \gls[#1]{#2}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\glsnogroupskiptrue

\newcommand{\PrintAcronyms}{%
  \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,nonumberlist]
}

\newcommand{\PrintGlossary}{%
  \printglossary[type=main,nonumberlist]
}

\newcommand{\PrintIndex}{%
  \bgroup
   \glsnogroupskipfalse
   \renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{##1}}%
  \printglossary[type=index,style=mcolindexgroup]
  \egroup
}
```

Now we have a test document, called `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{test-datagidx}% use datagidx
%\input{test-glossaries}% use glossaries

% Define some acronyms

\newacronymterm{html}{hypertext markup language}
\newacronymterm{csv}{comma-separated variable}

% Define some glossary entries

\newentry[description={A typesetting language},sort={TeX}]{tex}{\TeX}
\newentry[description={A format of \TeX},sort={LaTeX}]{latex}{\LaTeX}

% Define some acronyms that also go in the glossary

\newacronymentry{pdf}{portable document format}{A file format}

% Define some terms that aren't an acronym or a glossary entry

\newindexentry{sample}
\newindexentry{comma}
\newindexentry{cat}

\begin{document}

First use: \xgls{html}.
First use: \xgls{csv}.
First use: \xgls{pdf}.
Reference \xgls{tex}.
Reference \xgls{latex}.
Reference the \xgls{sample} term.
Reference the \xgls{comma} term.
Reference the \xgls{cat} term.

\clearpage

Second use: \xgls{html}.
Second use: \xgls{csv}.
Second use: \xgls{pdf}.
Reference \xgls{tex}.
Reference \xgls{latex}.
Reference the \xgls{sample} term.
Reference the \xgls{comma} term.
Reference the \xgls{cat} term.

\PrintAcronyms
\PrintGlossary
\PrintIndex
\end{document}
```

This uses `datagidx` if you have `\input{test-datagidx}` and it uses `glossaries` if you have `\input{test-glossaries}`. (Don't uncomment both at the same time!) With the first approach you need three `pdflatex` calls. With the second approach you need `pdflatex`+`makeglossaries`+`pdflatex`+`pdflatex`. When you switch between the two, make sure you delete the `.aux` file before recompiling.

First approach (`\input{test-datagidx}`):

Page 1:

[image: Image of page 1]

Page 2:

[image: Image of page 2]

Second approach (`\input{test-glossaries}`):

Page 1:

[image: Image of page 1]

Page 2:

[image: Image of page 2]

There are slight differences in the glossary/acronym/index styles. These can be tweaked depending on how you want the actual output to appear.

**Edit:** You can adapt the code of `\xgls` to define analogous commands for variants, such as upper case, plurals, short or long forms. Just change `\gls` in the definition to the appropriate command. For example, to define `\xglspl` for the `glossaries` version:

```
\newcommand{\xglspl}[2][]{%
  \ifglsentryexists{acronym.#2}%
  {%
    \ifglsentryexists{glossary.#2}%
    {\glsadd{glossary.#2}}%
    {}%
    \ifglsentryexists{index.#2}%
    {\glsadd[#1]{index.#2}}%
    {}%
    \glspl[#1]{acronym.#2}%
  }%
  {%
    \ifglsentryexists{glossary.#2}%
    {%
      \ifglsentryexists{index.#2}%
      {\glsadd{index.#2}}%
      {}%
      \glspl{glossary.#2}%
    }%
    {%
      \ifglsentryexists{index.#2}%
      {\glspl[#1]{index.#2}}%
      {%
        \glspl[#1]{#2}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
```

Note that with the `glossaries` version, with the above definition you can still have the final optional argument that follows the mandatory argument, but you can't have this for the `datagidx` version, which is another reason for just sticking with `glossaries`.